# How to rename the file extension, by removing archive dates

Tags: python, file, rename

I am thinking this code should take all my files within the folder, and rename .pdf_(date) to .pdf. However, it is not.

```
import os,sys
folder = 'C:\/MattCole\/test'
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
       infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
       if not os.path.isfile(infilename): continue
       oldbase = os.path.splitext(filename)
       newname = infilename.replace('.pdf*', '.pdf')
       output = os.rename(infilename, newname)
```

Example: file1.pdf_20160614-050421  renamed to file.pdf

There would be multiple files in the directory. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I have also tried counting the extension and used `'.pdf????????????', '.pdf'`

Comment: You can't use wildcards like '*' in python's `str.replace` function.

Comment: Try `re.sub` instead, you can define a regular expression to replace.

Comment: Never used re.sub before. Looks like I would need to identify the pattern as well.

Comment: Never used re.sub before. Looks like I would need to identify the pattern as well.      pattern = re.sub(r"\d", "", arp)                          So my code would be something like:   import os,sys
folder = 'C:\/MattCole\/test'
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
       infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
       if not os.path.isfile(infilename): continue
       oldbase = os.path.splitext(filename)
       newname = re.sub('pattern', '.pdf')
       output = os.rename(infilename, newname)                                      ?

Comment: `file1.pdf` or `file.pdf`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit silly, you've got some perfectly good code here that you're not using. You should use it.

```
import os,sys
folder = 'C:\/MattCole\/test'
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
       infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
       if os.path.isfile(infilename):
           oldbase, oldext = os.path.splitext(infilename)
           if oldext.startswith('.pdf'):           
               output = os.rename(infilename, oldbase+'.pdf')
```

Comment: Perfect. I knew I had to be close. Thanks Wayne.

Answer (score 0):

You want to split the old file name on _, then take the first part as new name:

```
>>> old_name = 'file1.pdf_20160614-050421'
>>> new_name = old_name.split('_')[0]
>>> new_name
'file1.pdf'
```

Comment: I was thinking that also. Splitting the extension, then keeping the first index. I was able to rename individual files, but wasn't able to do multiple files. Thanks for the reply.